# What is the format of a call to this code?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code, (which I did not write):

```
- (BOOL)execute:(NSString *)sqlCommand error:(NSError **)error
{
    const char *sql = [sqlCommand UTF8String];
    char *errorPointer;
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql, NULL, NULL, &errorPointer) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSString *errMsg = [NSString stringWithCString:errorPointer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *description = @"An error occurred executing the SQL statement";
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:description, NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, errMsg, NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey, nil];
            *error = [[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:SQLCipherManagerErrorDomain code:ERR_SQLCIPHER_COMMAND_FAILED userInfo:userInfo] autorelease];
            sqlite3_free(error);
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I also have a method without the "error" parameter, which I would call using something like this: [dm execute:insertCommand];

My question is:  what is the format of the call I would use for the method with the "error" parameter, so I can see any errors back from the call?

Comment: I'd say format isn't the right word. I'd rather say "how shall the call look like"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSError *error = nil; //your error
if(![dm execute:sqlCommand error:&error])
{ //Pass the address to your pointer ^^

    //Since you passed the address of your error pointer
    //your execute command was able to set it to an
    //NSError if one occurrs
}
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense (duh!)... what is the recommended method of handling SQLite errors? (such as doing an insert and the particulay key already exists in the table)?

Comment: If you feel the user should be alerted via pop up use `UIAlertView`

Comment: Or NSAlert, if you're writing for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

like that:

```
NSError* error = nil;
BOOL success = [dm execute:insertCommand error:&error];

if (success == NO)
{
  // do whatever if failed
}
```

see also ["Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC) from cocoa documentation.

Comment: You should fill out the example some more, to at least check the return value; the value in `error` will only be meaningful if the call actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to declare an `NSError` object outside of the call to the code, and pass in the address:

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [whateverObj execute:theSqlStmt error:&error];
if (!success) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: No, you don't have to create an error object - nor does your code do that.